# Convert JSON string to JavaScript Object for iterating

Tags: javascript, json

I Search but i cant find any solution. i get this string from server :

```
 [
  {
    'id': 0,
    'name': 'Adventure Works',
    'uniqueName': '[AdventureWorksDW2012Multidimensional-EE].[Adventure Works]'
  },
  {
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Channel Sales',
    'uniqueName': '[AdventureWorksDW2012Multidimensional-EE].[Channel Sales]'
  },
  {
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'Direct Sales',
    'uniqueName': '[AdventureWorksDW2012Multidimensional-EE].[Direct Sales]'
  },
  {
    'id': 3,
    'name': 'Finance',
    'uniqueName': '[AdventureWorksDW2012Multidimensional-EE].[Finance]'
  },
  {
    'id': 4,
    'name': 'Mined Customers',
    'uniqueName': '[AdventureWorksDW2012Multidimensional-EE].[Mined Customers]'
  },
  {
    'id': 5,
    'name': 'Sales Summary',
    'uniqueName': '[AdventureWorksDW2012Multidimensional-EE].[Sales Summary]'
  },
  {
    'id': 6,
    'name': 'Sales Targets',
    'uniqueName': '[AdventureWorksDW2012Multidimensional-EE].[Sales Targets]'
  }
]
```

But it is a string and i want it as a JavaScript Object. If i remove first and last`"` from string by hand every thing is ok but how to convert this string to JavaScript Object ?

**Update**

If i use jquery for parsing like this :

```
var data = $.parseJSON( response.d );
```

I get this error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '727' in {'id':0,'name':'Adventure Works','uniqueName':'[AdventureWorksDW2012Multidimensional-EE].[Adventure Works]'},{'id':1,'name':'Channel Sales','uniqueName':'[AdventureWorksDW2012Multi...<omitted>...'}
```

** Edit **

This is [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MBehtemam/89pRk/) link.

Comment: [`JSON.parse(yourString);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)?

Comment: After your update, you are not showing the relevant code. There is no `in` operator in the given codesample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse("[{...}]");` to convert it into Javascript object.

Comment: I try your way [here](http://jsbin.com/disegixa/1/edit?js,console) in jsbin but i get an error. `Unexcepted token '`

Comment: Yes. this is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MBehtemam/89pRk/) that i cant parse and iterate it.thanks

Comment: I realized the problem. Your JSON string is invalid. You should use double quotes in json, not single. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/89pRk/1/

Answer (score 1):

you can use `JSON.parse()` method for your JSON String to Javascript Object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
JSON.parse("some json stringified object")
```

To create string from json object use:

```
JSON.stringify(OBJECT);
```